# Como comparar dados do banco e exibir para o usuário

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, comparação

Eu tô desenvolvendo um site de surf. Nele, há uma seção chamada Minha Prancha Ideal.

Onde o usuário irá inserir seus dados (`Nome`, `email`, `peso`, `altura` e `experiencia`(iniciante, intermediario ou avançado)).

Eu irei salvar esses dados no banco e com base nas características do usuário (peso, altura e experiencia) eu irei dizer o tipo de prancha ideal.

A seção já está feita e também já está gravando os dados do usuário no banco. Eu recebi uma tabela/lista de referência com todas as medidas de prancha de acordo com a altura e peso do usuário.

[image: Tabela com os tamanhos da prancha de acordo com o perfil do usuário]

Para retornar a prancha ideal, eu preciso pegar os dados do usuário e comparar com essa tabela.

Pensei em fazer isso da seguinte maneira,

Dividi em três tableas/seções: `Experiencia`, `Peso e Altura` e `Modelo de prancha`.

Cada tabela/seção eu irei atribuir um ID:

Experiencia do usuário -> ID a,b,c 
Peso e Altura -> ID a,b,c,d....
Modelo de Prancha -> ID a,b,c,d....

[image: Experiencia do usuário]

Tabela com a experiência do usuário, um ID para cada.

[image: Peso e Altura]

Tabela com a relação do Peso e Altura do usuário, um ID para cada.

[image: Modelo de Prancha]

Tabela final com os modelos de prancham um ID para cada.

Para obter o resultado eu irei, de alguma forma, comparar a tabela `Experiencia` com a tabela `Peso+Altura`, gerando um ID ou número X que será comparada com o ID da terceira tabela (com os modelo de Prancha) e assim obtendo o resultado. Não sei se ficou muito claro a explicação, qualquer coisa podem me perguntar.

Minha dúvida é:
Esta correta essa minha lógica?
Esta é a melhor forma de fazer?
Em código, como posso fazer isso?

Qualquer tipo de ajuda é bem vinda!

Até agora eu só tenho o código que cadastra os dados no banco:

--Não creio que o HTML do formulário seja de grande utilidade. Caso solicitem, eu posto aqui ou no Pastebin.

```
function cadastrar($nome,$email,$estilo,$experiencia,$altura,$peso){          //INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO
     global $wpdb;
     // Minha tabela
    $table = 'aa_minhaprancha';

    // Inserindo os dados no array "data", responsável pelos dados a serem gravados no banco
    $data = array(
      'nome' => $nome,
      'email' => $email,
      'estilo' => $estilo,
      'experiencia' => $experiencia,
      'altura' => $altura,
      'peso' => $peso,
    );

    // run the insert
    $updated = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    // Se não ocorrer o update, retorna o erro
    if ( ! $updated ) {
      $wpbb->print_error();
    }

}
```

O banco é em Wordpress. Porém, não há problemas se houver algum help em MySql. Eu converto.

Recapitulando:

**O quero quero fazer?** - Exibir para o usuário o modelo de prancha ideal de acordo com o perfil dele.

**Como quero/estou fazendo?** - Pegando os dados do usuário (Nível de experiência, Altura, Peso e Tipo de prancha), comparando-os com a minha `lista de referência` e exibindo para o usuário.

**Como posso fazer isso?**

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que apresentou acredito que esteja buscando uma resposta que simplifique teu processo.

Então, eu faria da seguinte forma:

1. Criaria uma tabela única com todas as possibilidades mas por faixa de altura e peso (explico adiante).
2. Criaria uma ID única que atendesse às características do usuário, da seguinte forma:

   **NAAAPPPTTTT**

**Onde:**

**N** = **Nível** de experiência (pode ter mais de um dígito se for o caso), por exemplo **N** igual a **3** (Avançado)

**AAA** = Dígitos da **Altura** (sem a pontuação, por exemplo. **1,82** de altura seria igual a **182**. **Sugiro que use números que indiquem intervalos de altura**, por exemplo, **180** atenderia alturas de **1,80** a **1,8499**... e **185** de **1,85** a **1,8999**... Assim reduz as combinações (melhor se forem faixas mais amplas, como de dez em dez por exemplo)

**PPP** = Digitos do **Peso**, por exemplo, **96** de peso seria igual a **096** (idem a altura, sugiro fazer por faixa de pesos, neste exemplo, **96** seria **095**, pois corresponde à faixa de **95** a **99,999**... de peso)

**TTTT** = **Tipo** de prancha (neste caso **cada prancha deve ter um código único** de quantos dígitos precisar, eu fiz com quatro dígitos), por exemplo, prancha **0324**

Assim, para este usuário a prancha ideal teria a seguinte ID (com intervalos de 5 em 5 para o caso da altura e peso):

**31800950324**

Havendo uma tabela única com estas IDs indexadas adequadamente, resta somente fazer a busca.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Zkk, serviu a minha dica amigo?

Comment: E ai Zkk... serviu?

Answer (score -1):

Vamos lá. 
O que você basicamente quer fazer é modelar o banco de acordo com dados da tabela de surf, e dividir para que os mesmos tenham relacionamento entre si.

A exemplo: Você tem uma tabela chamada cliente:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES(
     idCliente INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Nome VARCHAR(100),
     Sexo CHAR(1),
     PRIMARY KEY(idCliente)
);
```

E outra tabela de documentos:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTOS(
    idDocumento INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idCliente INT,
    NOME_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR(100),
    VALOR_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR(200),
    idTipoDocumento INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(idDocumento)
);
```

E por último a tabela Tipo Documentos:

```
CREATE TABLE TIPO_DOCUMENTO(
    idTipoDocumento INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOME_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (idTipoDocumento)
);
```

Faremos agora alguns inserts :

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES (NULL, 'AMERICO SOUZA', 'M');
INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES (NULL, 'IGOR SOUZA', 'M');
INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES (NULL, 'MARIA QUITANDA', 'F');
INSERT INTO TIPO_DOCUMENTO VALUES (NULL,'RG');
INSERT INTO TIPO_DOCUMENTO VALUES (NULL,'CPF');
INSERT INTO TIPO_DOCUMENTO VALUES (NULL, 'TELEFONE');
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOS VALUES (NULL, 1, '123456789-67', 1);
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOS VALUES (NULL, 2, '093.356.879-90', 2);
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOS VALUES (NULL, 3, '+55(11)3622-5090', 3);
```

O banco foi modelado com o relacionamento 1:1, ou seja, uma entidade só pode se relacionar com apenas outra entidade. Então poderemos fazer o uso do JOIN (Junção) para unir os dados, já que estamos fazendo o uso de relacionamento.

```
SELECT CLI.NOME,
   DOC.VALOR_DOCUMENTO,
   TIPO.NOME_DOCUMENTO
FROM CLIENTES AS CLI
   INNER JOIN DOCUMENTOS AS DOC ON 
   (CLI.idCliente = DOC.idCliente)
   INNER JOIN TIPO_DOCUMENTO AS TIPO ON 
   (TIPO.idTipoDocumento = Doc.idTipoDocumento)
```

E temos o seguinte resultado:

[image: Consulta]

Caso você queira filtrar mais resultados, pode-se adicionar a clausula WHERE 
na qual você conseguirá além das tuplas da junção, pode determinar para quais condições você deseja o resultado.

Acredito que com este exemplo você consegue avançar. 
Para maiores dúvidas sugiro dar uma lida sobre SQL, JOINS, WHERE e Relacionamentos.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13527/1